# Network layers (from Computer Networks, Tanenbaum)

Tags: networking

"The purpose of each layer is to offer certain services to the 
higher layers, shielding those layers from the details of how the offered services are actually implemented."

Now the purpose of each layer is to offer services to the higher layers. How about the highest layer, there is no more layers to offer services to, so either is sentence isn't correct, or it's missing.

Comment: The user is the highest layer. And this isn't a question.

Comment: Layer 8 is politics; layer 9 is economics; layer 10 is religion. Not sure what comes after that.

Comment: You're quite correct, it should be something like *"The purpose of each layer, other than the highest layer, is to offer..."*.  Send Tanenbaum an erratum ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, usually the service above that is human readable data. Whether it be a webpage or an email, so you could say the layer above is the human or at least the parser in the browser. However one can layer another layer on top anyway, as is done in say the twitter API, it's messages being sent back and forth across HTTP for example. So how 7 osi layers is not as clear cut as it used to be.

Comment: It's more how Tanenbaum has gone and defined it.

Answer (score 0):

The application layer is the layer where everything starts and ends. Therefore, there is no requirement of passing data to a higher level. It's an Exception of the statement